# How to put a flash or .swf on the middle?

Tags: html, css, actionscript-3, flash

can you tell me how to import a game on my website and put it on the middle? please :) and how to make the game screen bigger like armor games.

Here is my website:
http://www.greenpost.esy.es/game.php

and my code is here:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Greenpost's Games</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="600" id="rocketman" ALIGN="">
            <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="flash/rocketman.swf">
            <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
            <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
            <EMBED src="flash/rocketman.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320px" HEIGHT="240px" NAME="rocketman" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </EMBED>
        </OBJECT>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your object tags in a div and centre that div using css styles.

```
div {
    margin 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your flash object in a div and then give a  `margin:0 auto` and `text-align:center` for horizontal center or use `positon:absolute` with `left` and `right` for vertical center.

```
<div id="flash_container">
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="600" id="rocketman" ALIGN="">
            <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="flash/rocketman.swf">
            <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
            <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
            <EMBED src="flash/rocketman.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320px" HEIGHT="240px" NAME="rocketman" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </EMBED>
        </OBJECT>
</div>
```